# javascript for getting the text from particular position in iphone or ipad

Tags: iphone

I am developing an epub ebook application.
I did the pagination for 1xhtml file, depending on the length of the text numbers of pages will increase.Now I need to get the text from starting of the UIWebView(x and y co-ordinates are 0.0f,0.0f) to a particular position(may be 200.0f,200.0f),how can i get it using java script or any other means.

Please help me.

Thank you in advance.
Shiva.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution if any one need it please use the javascript API getElementFromPoint(x,y).

Shiva.